# Blocking one axis Input while the other is used

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am able to rotate a cube on the axis with the greater mouse input, but don't know how to block input of the minor axis until mouse up.

The script includes a snap to the nearest 90 degree angle. Not so elegant, but I'll leave that for another post.

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class s_rotate_test : MonoBehaviour {
    float mouseX;
    float mouseY;

    public float rotationSpeed = 100f;
    public float smoothing = 2f;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()  {
        Debug.Log (transform.rotation.x + " | " + transform.rotation.y + " | " + transform.rotation.z);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if(Input.GetMouseButton(0)) {
            mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
            mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

            float rotationY = -mouseX * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            float rotationX = mouseY * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

            if (mouseX * mouseX > mouseY * mouseY) {
                transform.Rotate (0, rotationY, 0 /*, Space.World*/);
            } else if (mouseY * mouseY > mouseX * mouseX) {
                transform.Rotate (rotationX, 0, 0/*, Space.World*/);
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0)) {
            // Y AXIS SNAPS -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            if (transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y > 0 && transform.rotation.eulerAngles.y <= 45) {
                Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler (0, 0, 0);
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp (transform.rotation, targetRotation, smoothing);
            }
        }
    }
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

Comment: Please remember to use clear and understandable titles :)

Comment: [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please.

Comment: Sorry guys. I'm new here. I've updated the title. (Hope thats better). Working on mvce.

Comment: A greater mouse input means a greater value of `mouseX(Y)*mouseX(Y)`?

Comment: I think that's easy: 1. determine the greater axis once mouse button is just pressed and starts moving; 2. block the minor axis by setting a boolean flag; 3. unblock when the mouse button is released by resetting the flag.

Comment: i multiplied the input against itself to get an absolute comparison. without that i was getting a comparison between a positive and negative value which would falsely indicate that, for example: an input of +5 on the X axis, was shorter than a distance of -21 on the y axis.

Comment: Thanks again zwcloud for the suggestion, but the issue i would have is that even if i blocked the minor axis within either IF statement, the next frame would be a fresh check. Therefore, it allows input from the other axis all over again if it happens to be greater.

Answer (score 0):

You need something to keep track of the current dragging state.

```
public enum State{
  Normal,
  DraggingX,
  DraggingY
}
// This is a field
State draggingState = State.Normal;
```

With this setup, you check the biggest input only when the state is `Normal`.
After you determined the correct axis, you set the state to `DraggingX` (or Y).
When the mouse is pressed, you do this:

```
switch(dragginState){
  case State.Normal:
    // Get Greatest input (suppose it's X)
    draggingState = State.DraggingX;
    break;
  case State.DraggingX:
    // Use only X input
    break;
  case State.DraggingY:
    // Use only Y input
    break;
}
```

When it's released you set: `draggingState = State.Normal;` again.